# Javascript file being loaded when it shouldnt be

Tags: javascript

So I have a website which has a variety of what I call apps. Each app has its own folder and does something different. The structure is like this:

```
/appsfolder/
```

then for each app

```
/appsfolder/name of app/
/appsfolder/name of app/js.min.js
/appsfolder/name of app/index.php
/appsfolder/name of app/help.php
```

then some general files

```
/appsfolder/generic_javascript.js
/appsfolder/css.min.css
```

I have written seven apps with no problem up until now. Then I wrote an eighth app, and that has made a few things go a bit funny, to be specific and clear, let me run you through.

```
I run app 1 - No problem.
I run app 2-7. No problem.
I run app 8, the new app. No problem.
I run app 1 again. NOW app 1 is overlayed with app 8, the NEW app.
```

I have tried renaming the javascript file of app 8, but to no avail, its the same issue.

The ONLY difference in app 8 than in the others, is I used requestAnimFrame to animate the diagram each one of the apps generates (no animation in the others, just static images), and I obfuscated the javascript code when I minimised it.

Every index.php file is the same format, every database entry for each app  is the same format. And the app 8 runs just fine which means everything is in the correct position in the database and file structure... it just overlays onto the old apps.

The old apps do not interfere with one another, its only the new app.

I dont know what I could post to help that isnt reams of code, and ALSO the site is not live so I cant give you a version of that. I just wondered if anybody has any suggestions for what might cause this?

Thank you.
Alex

EDIT: Oh! My site is all Ajax based, there are no page reload, just subsequent Ajax calls. Could js.min.js be loading the first time, but then every subsequent time a new js.min.js is called it overwrites the old one?

Every app that isnt the new one uses a draw() function to draw to the canvas, but the new one does this:

```
draw() {
    // one time calculations
    animate();
}

animate() {
    // draw stuff to canvas
    requestAnimFrame(animate);
}
```

So maybe I need to think about how I could unload a javascript file after the user navigates away from the page?

Comment: Without any code or a demo its really just guessing.

Comment: You need to show us how the files are loaded using ajax - including how you are interpreting the js files once loaded (are they loaded from the index.php of the individual app or are they loaded using ajax?).